# I want to add all the amount AS a Total ... please help me how to write a query for that

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

This is my query .i want do the sum of amount ... but i am not getting how to get the sum of whole amount . please help me out .

```
SELECT AllocateAsset.Item, AllocateAsset.ItemModel,
    COUNT(AllocateAsset.ItemModel) AS CountOfItem,
    (CountOfItem * (
        SELECT Rate
        FROM rateList
        WHERE rateList.MakeModel = AllocateAsset.ItemModel
                   )
    ) / 4 AS Amount , SUM(Amount) AS Total
FROM aboutPM INNER JOIN
(
    AllocateAsset INNER JOIN PMReport
    ON AllocateAsset.ID=PMReport.AssetID
)
ON aboutPM.ID = PMReport.AboutPMID
WHERE (((aboutPM.Year)="2015") AND ((aboutPM.Period)="Jan-Feb-Mar"))
GROUP BY AllocateAsset.Item, AllocateAsset.ItemModel, CountOfItem, Amount
ORDER BY AllocateAsset.Item
```

Comment: Does this query even run at all?  Can you include a description of what you are trying to do?

Comment: yea this query runs if i remove SUM(Amount) As Total ... i want to add all the numbers that i get in Amount column ... i tried using Sum function but i  can not get the result ... it is like bill summary

Comment: Please provide an error message, when you add `SUM(Amount) As Total`

Comment: no error comes its just a blank column , the Total column comes blank ... i want to calculate all the Amount

Answer (score 0):

Remove Amount column from `Group by` list

```
GROUP BY AllocateAsset.Item, AllocateAsset.ItemModel, CountOfItem, Amount
```